# Расположение Исполнители ролей в некоторых версиях 1C

Tags: 1с, интерфейс, документация

На странице [1С Документооборот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynmvNLKR3Bc&list=PLNEYn0fUU1DmL9IoM-W8prXuWjLav5Bby&index=1&t=260s)

в интерфейсе есть пункт меню Исполнители ролей. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в моей версии 1С:Документооборот есть только Роли исполнителей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как найти Исполнители ролей. (см. также [Киберфорум](https://www.cyberforum.ru/1c-custom/thread2773281.html#post15202798), но там я не нашел где находится Функции технического специалиста)

Answer (score 0):

Куча вариантов:

1. Удалено
2. Переименовано
3. Перенесено
4. Не хватает прав

Это я только навскидку взял. Увы, 1С:Документооборот не знаю